# jquery_ujs issue: Font Awesome animated spinner works in Chrome but Not Safari

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

I am using [font-awesome-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/font-awesome-rails) in my rails project.  When the user clicks the submit button on a form:

- within the submit button there should be an animated font-awesome spinner, and the text within the button should change to saying "Submitting...".
- the button should be disabled so that the user is unable to submit the form multiple times.

The following code works perfectly when using Google Chrome:

```
<%= f.button "Submit", class: "btn btn-success", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Submitting..."} %>
```

In Safari however:

- the button is successfully disabled
- *But* the spinner icon does *not* appear, and the text does *not* change.

I created a tiny app to show the issue.  [The repo is here](https://github.com/ntistephens/loading_animation). Submit the `blog` form on Chrome and then submit it in Safari.  You will notice that the animation works on Chrome but not safari.

I saw [this issue on jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/306).  There are some quite verbose work arounds, but nothing that is convenient for re-use for all the places I want to implement this functionality.

It appears to be a browser issue: something like Safari doesn't want to do some additional processing once a form is submitted because it doesn't want to slow things down.

Chris Oliver from GoRails pointed out to me that if you run the following in the console, even in Safari: it triggers the desired effect:

```
$.rails.disableFormElement($("button"))
```

So the effect works in safari.  It just doesn't work when that is bound to a form submission button. I have attempted doing this with Safari version 9.1.2, as well as 10.0.1.  I have also attempted in Rails 4.2.6 and Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

There might just be a nice quick-fix... See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q38do4qe/), which is an even smaller minimal example of the problem. On Safari 10.1, the refresh is broken about 70% of the time for me.

Then we force hardware acceleration to be used, through CSS:

```
form {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

And [the problem goes away](https://jsfiddle.net/q38do4qe/1/).

Note: technically the first line of CSS should be enough to force hardware acceleration, but the second line most definitely is needed here for this to work...

Comment: I tested this solution on safari 9.1.2.  Unfortunately the issue still persists.  I see you mentioned the specific version of Safari 10.1.  Does this mean it only works on that version of safari or later?

Comment: @Neil: that's a shame - it is consistently working for me on 10.1, on two different machines. Out of interest - is it the fiddle that's not working for you, or the integration with your code? I've just had a quick go on BrowserStack, and it _appears_ to be working on El Capitan / 9.1, Yosemite / 8, Mavericks / 7.1 and even Mountain Lion 6.2...

Comment: oh it works in your fiddle example.  It doesn't work in my example app.